# FullCalendar: Rendering background events as regular ones

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm writing an app that employs Fullcalendar. I need to have two view/edit modes:

- one typical - *Regular edit* - with regular and background events, where regular events are editable through clicking and background ones are only drawn as informative areas
- and another - *Background edit* - where regular events are hidden (`return false`), and the background events are rendered as regular ones, with editing capability through clicking.

Something along these lines:

```
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        if($('#background-edit-chk').is(':checked')) {
            if (event.rendering == EVENT_RENDERING.NORMAL) return false;
            else event.editable = true; // here: render background as editable
        }
    }
```

What would be the code in the `else` line - obviously the above code does not render event as regular.

I mean, I could re-fetch the events and use separat transformation function for each mode, but I'm hoping that there's a way to just act on the rendering layer.

Answer (score 0):

i have exactly 30minutes experience with fullcalendar,
but perhaps

> event.rendering = ""

(making the rendering property empty should render the event as a normal event)